# How to convert .CSV File Non Unicode String Type to Integer using SSIS Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis

I am exporting data from a site called Linnworks for company orders that gives me a .CSV file that contains Non-Unicode characters. Inside the file looks like this

```
Order Id
"102077"
"102841"
"102320"
"101837"
"102427"
"102980"
"103545"
```

I create a SSIS Project on Visual Studio and I have this on my Data Flow.
[Data Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sntuY.png)

These are my settings for the Flat File Source. [General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A30z.png) [Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ntDs.png) [Advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWbBy.png)

Next I have the Data Convert Block in order to convert the String into Integer. The problem I am having is that when I choose Four-Byte Signed Integer and click okay it does not save and goes back to Text Stream. [Data Convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEhS6.png)

Settings for my OLE DB Connection to my Microsoft SQL Server and the table I created. [Create Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiJNP.png) [Table Mappings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIpfv.png)

How am I able to import the .CSV file into a table with the proper data type? And why do my settings for the Data Convert not save?

Debug Result. I am sure it is because it is trying to import the String into the Table int type but that is what I am trying to accomplish.[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76SKl.png)

Comment: Change the data type in Advanced to DT_STR and not text stream. Streams are a way different animal.

Comment: You also have a text qualifier of quote("). Just put " in that box.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much! @KeithL